# How to find out if parent have children in php mysql

Tags: mysql

It have two table parent table and children table

**Parent Table**

```
id   page-title    page-content
```

**Children Table (where parent_id = id) id from parent table**

```
child_id   parent_id   child-title   child-content
```

**Now How to find out if parent have any children**

```
<?php
//parent table
$data = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM parent_page ORDER BY id DESC");
while($rows = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) ):
    $parent_id = $rows->id;
?>

<?php 
    //chlidren table
    $child_data= $conn->query("SELECT * FROM children_page WHERE parent_id = $parent_id ");
    while($child_rows = $child_data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) ):
         $child_rows->parent_id;
 ?>
<?php
//requirement check if parent have children (how to check if parent have children or not)
if('parent have children'){
    then echo children content;
}else{
    echo parent content;
}
?>

<?php endwhile; endwhile;?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have no idea in PHP. But you can do this by changing your query.

```
Select * 
from Children c
left Join Parent p on p.id = c.parent_id
```

> You can check parent_id value.

`If Parent_id value null then no parent avaialble. If it is not null parent is Available.`

Answer (score 1):

Get the number of rows in the child query. If it's more than zero, the parent has children.

You should also use a prepared query instead of substituting variables directly into the SQL.

```
<?php
$child_data = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM children_page WHERE parent_id = :parent");
$child_data->bindParam(':parent', $parent_id);
//parent table
$data = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM parent_page ORDER BY id DESC");
while($rows = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) ):
    $parent_id = $rows->id;
?>

<?php 
    //chlidren table
    $child_data->execute();
    if ($child_data->rowCount()) {
        // parent has children
        while($child_rows = $child_data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) ): 
            // echo children content
            ?>
<?php endwhile;
}else{
    echo parent content;
}
?>

<?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: its solved the issue, but don't have enough privilege to appreciated the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<php //children table 
     $child_data= $conn->query("SELECT * FROM children_page WHERE parent_id = $parent_id "); 
        
        while($child_rows = $child_data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) ): 
          $child_rows->parent_id; 
  ?>
```

Comment: it will only execute parent_id from children table

Comment: It would help if you explained your answer.